# how to use the -skipFKConst option can only be given with -constraints option

Tags: enterprisedb

I have used offline migration command to create an SQL scripts but I need to omit the migration of foreign key constraints. So I have used the below commands but getting this error :

```
'MTK-03000: General Error
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

One or more schema objects could not be imported during the migration process. Please review the migration output for more details.

Command:

```
./runMTK.sh -offlineMigration /home/enterprisedb/offline_scripts_for_target/table_ddl
    -targetSchema targetschema -schemaOnly -constraints -skipFKConst
    -tables table_name sourceschema
```

Please help me how to use `skipFKConst`.